# ¿Como ocultar el valor de un campo?

Tags: laravel, html5, laravel-blade

Lo que quiero llevar acabo es el manejo de un dato de alta seguridad el cual el usuario debe ingresar pero si ingreso como tipo contraseña el campo en html una persona con conocimientos en desarrollo web podria modificar el type="password" del campo y cambiarlo a text y de esa manera visualiza el valor real, de que manera puedo distorsionar dicho valor para que no sea reconocible

intente con un hash al valor con md5 pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: creo que no entiendo bien la pregunta. Si el usuario debe ingresar el dato... por qué lo enviarías a una vista? Si no devuelves el dato desde el backend, tal cual como laravel hace con el password de los usuarios.... cual sería el problema?

Comment: El problema es que dicho formulario es una segunda instancia para completar, por ende en el primer formulario que es enviado al usuario el llena toda la información desde cero, pero este nuevo formulario es para que dicho usuario bien sea complete, verifique o modifique los datos que subió en el formulario anterior por ende la información debe mostrarse pero únicamente dicho campo no puede mostrarse debido a la privacidad

Comment: Ok, entonces cual es la diferencia con el password? Cuando un usuario se registra elige un `password` (primer formulario), luego va a su sección de perfil (nuevo formulario) donde puede verificar o modificar los datos que subió en el formulario anterior, **puede modificar (o no) el password, pero no puede verlo, porque no está ahí**

Comment: Las contraseñas nunca se mandan al cliente, porque dichas contraseñas pueden ser interceptaras por programas de tercero, es decir, antes de que un usuario le de a f12 o depure para ver las contraseñas, ya están más que capturadas por otros programas...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregarlo al array `$hidden` en el Modelo donde esté el atributo que quieres ocultar:

```php
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
*/
protected $hidden = [
    'nombre_del_atributo_a_ocultar'
];
```